# Safe, sensible to turn off BRANCH circuit breaker for range, every day when house is empty?

Tags: safety

After one oven turned itself on middle night, everyone in my family is now scared stiff silly of ranges!!! We always turn off all Branch Circuit Breakers ("BCB") except for fridge, before we leave condo to vacation. We livein  Toronto Canada. [Certified ON technician found nothing wrong](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/178330/96467).

Still we want turn off BCB for range EVERY TIME WE LEAVE HOUSE – ALMOST EVERY DAY – this is how much we distrust ovens! But [this website](https://www.agingcare.com/questions/switch-can-turn-electric-stove-off-on-when-we-come-back-426645.htm) discourages it.

> [golden23](https://www.agingcare.com/members/golden23) Mar 2017
>
> You are right, katiekate. They are not for regular flipping. A switch installed by an electrician would be better or remove all the knobs before you leave the house.
>
> [Katiekate](https://www.agingcare.com/members/katiekate) Mar 2017
>
> I would not be flipping the circuit breaker off and on. They are not designed to act like a light switch...they will not stand up to the wear involved.

As you request I picture my Circuit Breakers and range details.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you use it so often, you should get a separate switch. You don't want to wear out your breaker so it doesn't work when you need it most.

Comment: as i said in your first post ... are you sure that you did not set it to turn on in the middle of the night?

Comment: You should check if you can set your watch to it.

Comment: Is it possible that someone in your home once made an early breakfast and simply went back to bed forgetting to switch off the range? Anyone have a history of sleep walking? Does your range have rotating knobs or touch switches?  If it uses sensitive touch switches do you happen to have a cat that likes climbing onto the furniture (or on the range). Might your home be haunted?  If your convinced that the range turned on with out any intervention consider getting a new range. Regardless of the underlying reason be sure never to use the top surface of a cooking range for storage.

Comment: I would say it is not sensible. You are worrying about a very unusual mode of failure assuming that it was not some kind of error. It such a failure does occur, it would be unlikely to cause a fire assuming that the oven is closed and nothing flammable is stored inside. I would recommend never leaving an oven open or storing something flammable in it. There is a risk of the circuit breaker expiring prematurely, but a breaker failing in an unsafe manner is quite unusual.

Comment: one other thought ... contact the manufacturer .... they would be very interested in such a failure, if there actually was one

Comment: I have a different problem. A profoundly autistic daughter in her 30's who will turn on burners and leave them on. (Different reason, same problem.) My solution was to design and build a system at the stove which requires code access to activate the stove and which uses multiple sensors (radar and ultrasound) to monitor motion and activity. If the room is vacated for some given time (2 minutes, for example), then the relays are turned off and the stove is isolated from power. I use hybrid relays composed of both mechanical and TRIACs to minimize dissipation at 40 A, when operating.

Comment: @jonk don't homebrew mains stuff if you don't absolutely have to; there is serious danger there.  The switching problem in your design is easy; they make 40A air conditioning contactors which are more than adequate for switching a simple resistive load. That is the only thing that should touch mains. They are cheap (<$20) and a 24V furnace transformer is $10-ish. Make everything else low voltage, safe and easy.  You need only interrupt one 240V leg; if you choose the right leg, it will break the heaters but the oven light and controls will still work.

Comment: @Harper I started out using 60 A relays. But there were other considerations which I think justified adding semiconductors to remove arcing and to keep the dissipation while active to under 2 watts. These balancing act considerations would get us into a discussion here that commenting probably won't support. The switching system required significant attention, I grant. (By the way, I don't use TRIACs but pairs of SCRs for hybrid switching which I feel is more robust and manageable.) But the sensor arrangements and data fusion software was also "interesting" to get working "just so."

Comment: @jonk: I'd like to see your schematics/parts list. Sounds interesting. I used zero-crossing solid-state relays to switch 240v to a pool pump. The 240V SSR coil was fed via a 120V SSR which has a timer on it. The big mistake in my setup was using a mechanical timer. I need to redo it with an electronic one.

Comment: @Pamela Lee - Are you talking about every day when you leave the house, or seasonally?  A "switch duty" rated breaker is necessary for daily operation or more frequent operation as a switch, but for once every few weeks or months, a standard breaker should be fine.

Comment: @batsplatsterson Yes, once every day whenever the house is empty.

Comment: That unit has a lockout function. Have you tried it?

Comment: @PamelaLee, do you have pets?  In my case, I had a "stove turning on in the middle of the night" problem that turned out to be my dog climbing up to lick an empty pan, and knocking the controls.  The solution was removing the knobs when not in use and/or not leaving pans with good smelling residue on the stove.

Comment: If it were me, and I had a reasonable suspicion that the device itself turn itself on (as opposed to a human in the house making a mistake), no matter what a technician found, I'd replace the device as soon as I could afford to.

Answer (score 3):

I can’t quite make out the brand of breaker or the age. If you are using the circuit breaker like a switch it should be switch rated “SWD”  stamped on the breaker or the breaker is listed for switch duty. Many modern breakers are listed for switch duty but not stamped. 
The one advantage you have is the oven s not on when you throw the breaker off or on, this helps but constantly flipping the breaker not rated for switch duty damages the hammers and can cause early failure.

Comment: hi. thanks. i can take more close up pictures if you want? what you want me to zoom in?

Comment: I don’t recognize the panel and the breakers look to be Snyder but that’s all I can see , if we know the type of breaker it may be switch duty rated so it would not be a problem to turn it off and on by the breaker.

Comment: i added a picture. do you need more?

Comment: I don't think you'll find SWD breakers rated greater than 20A, the purpose of the rating is switch fluorescent lighting and greater than that misses the point of the rating. You will find HID rated breakers in higher amperage, also a lighting application.  The NEC 404..11 allows standard breakers to be used as a switch .

Comment: @nosparksplease, I  ~agree with your reasoning kind of, the NEC allows switch rated breakers to be used for switching but not under load unless rated. 404.11 states in the event of a power failure the breaker can be used as a switch..  all square D QO breakers are switch rated I have been looking for the S1 Schneider listing but have not found the listing information. 240.83.D is the section you should be looking at as it specifically mentioned used for switches they should be marked SWD or HID. I use square d QO as they are made to toggle more often under load or not compared to HOM or others

Answer (score 2):

Leaving circuit breakers on during vacation like holiday trips, except for essential devices like heating system for freezing protection and refrigerators, may be a **problem in some insurance contracts**. There were cases in Europe where appartments were left only for a 2 hours' shopping without switching off all electric items, and the laptop's power supply plugged into the 230V outlet started a fire. The insurance **refused to pay the damage** and won in court.
A look into the insurance contract(s) may help.

In Europe, **most domestic fires start in the kitchens**.
As mentioned in other comments, pets and non-pet animals, sleep walkers, older people with Alzheimer, a long emotional telephone call - normal ovens and plates have a certain risk.

One way to reduce the risk is to replace normal electric oven and hotplates with a combined **microwave oven** (MW + grill + oven) and **induction plates**.
A MW oven can only operate if the door is closed, and the **time is automatically limited**. Induction plates do only operate if a pot or pan is put on the plate, and the time is limited, too. The plates do not get hot by itself, but only indirectly by the contact with the pot - the **temperature will be much lower** compared to ceramic or convection plates.

Both devices can be each operated by a standard inexpensive switch - f.e. a plug- in adapter switch with indicator lamp -, since the wattage is less enough (f.e. 16A @ 230V).

The low temperature of the plate is **saving time and energy** in multiple ways - f.e. the danger of burning-ins in the plates or their surrounding from over-boilings is much less saving again energy/chemical detergents and time.
So by saving energy costs, the **investment** should be returned in a couple of years. And of course, it is more **environment-friendly**.

Comment: "There were cases in Europe where appartments were left only for a 2 hours' shopping without switching off all electric items" sources please? pls add them to your answer – no need make new comment.

Comment: @PamelaLee
I learned that from a lawyer, but couldn't find any hint in the Internet.
It may be annoying to shut down the PC/Laptop everytime the user leaves home. 
But there is a possibility to change the behaviour of the physical on/off button of most computer systems to go into hibernate status rather to shut down every running program. After pushing the button again and logging in, the system will be in the exactly same status as before.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't trust the switches on your range, why should you trust your circuit breakers? Do they just seem more robust? The "fast" way to disconnect power to your range is the switch that comes pre-installed. In answer to your actual question, though - would something like [this](https://www.zoro.com/schneider-electric-circuit-breaker-smart-home-120240v-30a-qo230plilc/i/G6636131/) work for you? It's a "Smart Circuit Breaker", features are listed as follows:

> Features: Offers Remote Control Capability with Overload and Short-Circuit Protection of Your Electrical System, Accessory That Enables Remote Control of The Connected Device, Allows Devices to Be Managed Without Sacrificing Convenience or Comfort