# Certified ON technician said nothing wrong with Frigidaire oven, but it still smells smoky. Second opinion?

Tags: stove

[Sequel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/178149/96467). Bro's wife's boss found her  technician certified by Ontario to inspect Frigidaire range yesterday. He found nothing wrong – he opened display panel on cook top, tested electricity, and no electricity leaked. He said he saw no evidence  the oven turned itself on to bake – he said he believes customers, but not this time. He said not worry about smoky smell. He charged $200 CAD, but he offered return for free if still issue.

After technician she never used range and opened open door to air out smokyness.  Oven has always been empty. But today oven smells smoky again. The oven hasn't turned itself on again.

1. Anyone know why oven smells smoky when empty?
2. Smart for her to pay a second opinion – a different technician?

Comment: Is this a new range? I ask because new they may take some time to outgas , I would run a self clean cycle if it is a self cleaning model or set the temp high 500 and get it hot for a 1/2 hour after that there should not be any manufactures residue left. I doubt that I would pay that much for a second opinion, there is not much to a range.

Comment: @EdBeal Yes! You spotted my issue. thanks!